# Sony Vaio dekstop wireless keyboard won't type certain keys

Tags: keyboard, sony-vaio

I cannot type certain keys, p, m, return, couple of others.  I have made sure localization and keyboard settings are correct.  I have removed and installed new batteries, also tried just leaving them out.  I have tried a myriad of key combinations to reset the keyboard (both shift keys, control, alt, etc.).  Nothing has worked.  Num lock is not on, no function keys are on.  No keys are stuck.

Other keyboards work.  The keyboard in question was working fine 12 hours earlier.

This is a desktop all in one Sony, not a laptop.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

EDIT:  Nothing has been spilled on the keyboard.  No keys are stuck.

Comment: I knew a guy from China who disappeared off the web for 6 months. Apparently he was reading a comic strip and spewed tea all over his laptop. It took him 6 months to save for a system. ANYWAY, have you tried blowing out the keyboard with compressed air? Sometimes crumbs in the keyboard can make the key-presses not work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a stuck key preventing some other keys from working till it's unstuck.

Comment: sounds like it but I can't find anything.

Comment: It may simply be that the keycap isn't stuck, but the underlying mechanism is.  Does this keyboard work on another machine?

Comment: I had a Viao laptop and I had a problem like this. One of the keys wasn't stuck but became worn down, it was harder and harder to press it.

Comment: You've got lots of options - although your keyboard is a little pricey, you can get a cheap replacement for a few dollars. You can also see if it's still under warranty and send it in for fixing. Or, you can even fix it yourself thanks to lots of tutorials and videos.